# Node.js топ по монеткам

Tags: javascript

работаю со старым чистым **nodejs v14**, у меня есть **JSON** формата `{"id":{"coins":n,"nickname":"nick"}, ... }`
Нужно сделать топ 10 по монеткам, подскажите пожалуйста как можно это сделать, чтобы выводилось к примеру:

> 1. nick - 100 монет ...
> 2. nick - 5 монет ...

Comment: покажите полный пример json

Comment: @entithat `{"302751096005197834":{"coins":25996109,"nickname":"rxckeet#6969"},"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const arr = {
  "1": {
    "coins": 5,
    "nickname": "a#1111"
  },
  "2": {
    "coins": 3,
    "nickname": "b#1111"
  },
  "3": {
    "coins": 2,
    "nickname": "c#1111"
  }
};

const top10 = Object.entries(arr).sort((a,b) => b[1].coins - a[1].coins).slice(0, 10);

for (const [id, user] of top10) {
  console.log(user.nickname, user.coins);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, всё работает, но хотелось бы добавить ещё в начале
1.
2.
и т.д, нумерацию, подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать лучше с этим кодом

Comment: заменить `for-of` на `for-i`, `for(let i = 0; i < ... ) { clg(i + 1, top10[i]...`

Comment: Выводит айдишники и `[object Object]`

Comment: Да, потому что `top10[i]` это объект ваш. `top10[i][1].nickname`

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое :) Очень выручили

Comment: пожалуйста.....